# Mockito's Matcher vs Hamcrest Matcher?

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

This is going to be an easy one, but I cannot find the difference between them and which one to use, if I have both the lib's included in my classpath?

Comment: Related: [How do Mockito matchers work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22822514/1426891)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Hamcrest matcher methods return `Matcher<T>` and Mockito matchers return T.  So, for example: `org.hamcrest.Matchers.any(Integer.class)` returns an instance of `org.hamcrest.Matcher<Integer>`, and `org.mockito.Matchers.any(Integer.class)` returns an instance of `Integer`.

That means that you can only use Hamcrest matchers when a `Matcher<?>` object is expected in the signature - typically, in `assertThat` calls.  When setting up expectations or verifications where you are calling methods of the mock object, you use the Mockito matchers.

For example (with fully qualified names for clarity):

```
@Test
public void testGetDelegatedBarByIndex() {
    Foo mockFoo = mock(Foo.class);
    // inject our mock
    objectUnderTest.setFoo(mockFoo);
    Bar mockBar = mock(Bar.class);
    when(mockFoo.getBarByIndex(org.mockito.Matchers.any(Integer.class))).
        thenReturn(mockBar);

    Bar actualBar = objectUnderTest.getDelegatedBarByIndex(1);
    
    assertThat(actualBar, org.hamcrest.Matchers.any(Bar.class));
    verify(mockFoo).getBarByIndex(org.mockito.Matchers.any(Integer.class));
}
```

If you want to use a Hamcrest matcher in a context that requires a Mockito matcher, you can use the `org.mockito.Matchers.argThat` (or `org.mockito.hamcrest.MockitoHamcrest.argThat` in [Mockito 2](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.18/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html)).  It converts a Hamcrest matcher into a Mockito matcher.  So, say you wanted to match a double value with some precision (but not much).  In that case, you could do:

```
when(mockFoo.getBarByDouble(argThat(is(closeTo(1.0, 0.001))))).
    thenReturn(mockBar);
```

Comment: Just noting that, in Mockito 2, the `argThat` overload that works with Hamcrest `Matcher`s was moved `MockitoHamcrest`. [What's new in Mockito 2](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#incompatible) discusses this in its "Incompatible changes with 1.10" section.