# Alternative to extending ArgumentMatcher for argument verification for mockito

Tags: mocking, mockito, argument-matcher

I was wondering if there is more elegant way to verify the arguments other than using a class that extends ArgumentMatcher?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for `ArgumentCaptor` as a way of doing this? Refer to http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#captors .  This lets you perform whatever checks you like on the values that were passed to your mock's methods.  It's often much simpler than setting up an `ArgumentMatcher`.

Comment: I'll also add the expressive FEST-Assert library in addition to `ArgumentCaptor`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "more elegant", but an alternative to implementing a custom ArgumentMatcher is to use the `Mockito.argThat` matcher that takes a [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) matcher as an argument.  There are many Hamcrest matchers available, both in the Hamcrest library itself and from third parties, so that could save you from writing your own custom argument matcher, but if there isn't one that you need already available, you can write a custom Hamcrest matcher instead of a Mockito ArgumentMatcher.  Whether that is more elegant or not is in the eye of the beholder.

An example of its use can be seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351055/316745) to [Mockito's Matcher vs Hamcrest Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348046/mockitos-matcher-vs-hamcrest-matcher).