# Classcast exception when using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I am getting classcast exception using the following bit of code in Test case.

```
  Employee employee1= new Employee();
  Employee employee2= new Employee();
  Employee employee3= new Employee();
  int id=1234;

  when(employee1.getID()).thenReturn(id);
  when(employee2.getID()).thenReturn(id);
  when(employee3.getID()).thenReturn(id);
```

I want to generalize this as

```
 when((((Employee)Matchers.any(Employee.class)).getID())).thenReturn(id);
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf cannot be cast to com.site.model.Employee
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi I know this is a very old question however I just got to this same problem myself today.

Anyway it has to do with how hamcrest handles Matchers. I basically doesn't return the given type but a wrapper around it.

The easiest way to fix it is to use any from mockito not hamcrest e.g.

```
when((((Employee)org.mockito.Matchers.any(Employee.class)).getID())).thenReturn(id);
```

For more details see this answer: [comparison with mockito and hamcrest matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348046/mockitos-matcher-vs-hamcrest-matcher)

Hope it helps anyone stumbling through this ;)

Comment: Cool answer! The only change is to use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any` as `org.mockito.Matchers.any` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that you need to typecast when using Mockito then you usually have something wrong.

I guess you are trying to do something like:

```
    Employee employee = Mockito.mock(Employee.class);
    when(employee.getId()).thenReturn(id);
```

Comment: Here employee is not fixed. I need to return same thing for the instance employee1 or employee2. Can you suggest how to do that

Comment: You should show more of your test code so that we can get some context

Comment: Sorry for limited information. I have updated the question. Can you help me.

Comment: What piece of logic are you trying to test?

Comment: It shall be independent of logic. I just need to return a constant value when the method is being invoked for all test cases.