# Spring JPA being able to use Any matchers in repository

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

So im trying to test my service layer and i have mocked my repository, what i want to do is

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TicketServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private TicketService ticketService;

    @Test
    public void test_buy_ticket_successfully() {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket(1, false, false, "");
        List<Ticket> availableTickets = Arrays.asList(ticket);

        Mockito.when(ticketRepository.findAllUnboughtAndUnpickedTickets()).thenReturn(availableTickets);
        Mockito.when(ticketRepo.findById(any(Integer.class)).thenReturn(Optional.of(any(Ticket.class));

        Ticket boughtTicket = ticketService.buyTicket("123");

        assertNotNull(boughtTicket);
        assertEquals(1, boughtTicket.getId());

        Mockito.verify(ticketRepository).findAllUnboughtAndUnpickedTickets();

    }
```

Error i get is :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Matcher<Integer> to Integer
```

All i want to do is use any matchers in the input and output, but this does not work as my repoistory is as follows:

```
public interface TickRep extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Integer>
```

Im using spring boot, junit 5.

Any ideas?

Comment: share your Junit class along with dependency and what exceptions are you getting?

Comment: @dassum updated the comments

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the line setting expectations:

`thenReturn(Optional.of(any(Ticket.class));`

The error you get

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Matcher<Integer> to Integer
```

suggests that you are using Hamcrest matchers, not Mockito matchers.

See [Mockito's Matcher vs Hamcrest Matcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348046/mockitos-matcher-vs-hamcrest-matcher)

- Mockito `any()` returns `T`,
- Hamcrest `any()` returns `Matcher<T>`

Second problem: even Mockito matchers cannot be used in context of a return value.

See: [How do Mockito matchers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work)

> Matcher methods can't be used as return values; there is no way to phrase `thenReturn(anyInt())` or `thenReturn(any(Foo.class))` in Mockito, for instance. Mockito needs to know exactly which instance to return in stubbing calls, and will not choose an arbitrary return value for you.