# Using Mockito argThat in a loop results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, mockito, matcher

One of the legacy tests uses Mockito `argThat` to stub corresponding results in a loop.

It is passing if I decrease the number of iterations to 1 (`numberOfItems = 1`, i.e. like if there's no loop).

As soon as it gets to the 2nd iteration, it errors out with NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "getValue()" because "arg" is null
```

The code is like this:

```
 @Test
 public void testMy() {
     int numberOfItems = 2;
     List<MyData> myDataList = getTestData(numberOfItems);
     
     for (MyData md : myDataList) {
         when(mockedService.someMethod(
                argThat(arg -> Objects.equals(arg.getValue(), md.getMyValue())))) // NPE here on arg.getValue()
             .thenReturn(getExpectedResult(md.getMyValue()));
     }
     
     List<MyData> resData = testService.methodUnderTest(myDataList);
     
     // assert... resData list has all the expected items and values
 }
```

The method being tested is similar to the following

```
public List<MyData> methodUnderTest(List<MyData> myDataList) {
    myDataList.forEach(myData -> {
            // ... some logic ...
        
            myData.setResult(mockedService.someMethod(new MyRequest(myData.getMyValue())));
        }
    });

    return myDataList;
}
```

But for the error case the method call is not even reached, coz NPE happens earlier in the unit test code.

Originally it was passing being used somewhat like this

```
when(mockedService.someMethod(
       argThat(hasProperty("value", equalTo(md.getMyValue())))))
    .thenReturn(getExpectedResult(md.getMyValue()));
```

however, I saw a recommendation to prefer comparing the objects directly, so I tried to re-write the stubbing as suggested, getting rid of those `equalTo` and `hasProperty`, bot now got into those NPE error :)

Any tips on what am I doing wrong, please? Thanks!!

Comment: What is the content of `myDataList`? Does it contain only non-null values?

Comment: @knittl yes, myDataList is beyond suspicion, the NPE is on `arg.getValue()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `when(mockedService.someMethod(argThat(arg -> Objects.equals(arg.getValue(), md.getMyValue())))).thenReturn(getExpectedResult(md.getMyValue()));` the first time, the method is stubbed. When you call it a second time, the existing stub tries to match the second stubbing call. `argThat` (and all other matcher methods) return `null`, which makes the matcher of your existing stub throw.

Two potential solutions:

- Change your matcher to `argThat(arg -> arg != null && ...)` to not match null inputs
- Don't use the `when(mock.call(argThat(...))).thenReturn(result)` form – which actually calls the method! –, but switch to `doReturn(result).when(mock).call(argThat(...))`

Comment: Exactly! The second approach did the thing, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to kind of solve it going from the other end.

Long story short, it all started after I upgraded to Java 17 and Mockito to 5.3.1, this made `argThat` incompatible with hamcrest `hasProperty` due to those `Matcher` / `ArgumentMatcher` incompatibility (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351055/2518705).

At this point I decided to replace those hamcrest matchers and faced the NPE.

Now I realized, I can make it work just by using `org.mockito.hamcrest.MockitoHamcrest.argThat` instead of `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.argThat`.

Meanwhile, the original question potentially could still have the separate correct answer :)